# Altering 1 C# controller file

Tags: c#

I've worked with PHP but never C#, and I need to make 1 change to a file, and was hoping I could get some guidance, or suggested resources to learn more.

I have 1 cs controller file where I want to change the `[Authorize(Roles="A")] to [Authorize(Roles="A,B")]`

I made the change but nothing happens, so I've come to the conclusion that this cs file probably needs to be compiled.

The question is, is there a way to compile this one file? Or does the entire site need to be compiled?

When I open the cs files, it opens with "Visual Studio Tools For Application 2.0 2008".

Is this sufficient to make the changes?

My thinking is that one of the following needs to happen:

**Scenario 1:**

- Open the .cs file in the appropriate compiler (of which I do not know
  what it is) Compile it and copy the newly compiled file into the
  appropriate folder.

**Scenario 2:**

- Open the whole project in a compiler - of which I'm guessing the
  ".csproj" file to open. Compile the whole project Copy the desired
  compiled file to replace the old file.

**Scenario 2b:**

- Open the whole project in a compiler - of which I'm guessing the
  ".csproj" file to open. Compile the whole project Copy everything
  back to the server.

**Scenario 3:**

- The code I have is not sufficient to do the changes, and I need some
  other source code.

That's all I've got, if someone can suggestion which one(s) may be on the right track, and how I may go about doing this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Usually you need to recompile the whole project an deploy the files from the bin subfolder only.

Comment: Yes there is a .csproj file

Comment: Yes, sorry, I missed that. See my edited comment above. :-)

Comment: The appropriate compiler would be Visual Studio and you need to open the csproj file (or sln file), and this would need recompiling and copying over to the server

Comment: When I double click on the .csproj it tells me that its a "User Options File" - is this the file I'm looking for?

Comment: The .suo file is the one with the user options. Do you have Visual Studio installed?

Answer (score 0):

The fact you are talking about a **Controller** would strongly suggest you are working on an **ASP .NET MVC** project. You will have a `.sln` file which is a solution file which is the master document if you will:

- YourWebsiteSolution.sln

  - YourWebsiteProject.csproj

    - YourController.cs

Once you open the `.sln` file with Visual Studio (you need to know what version but you can get the latest here: [Download VS2012 Web Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng#products/visual-studio-express-for-web)). You can the choose **Build -> Build -> ReBuild Solution** from the menu and that will re-compile all of your `.cs` and associated files into DLLs that will be in your `\Solution\Project\bin\Debug` folder (or Release depending on build).

When you deploy to the server you only deploy the .DLL files (in this instance). You **NEVER** deploy the actual `.cs` files as they contain the code and you don't want people peeking into them (this differs from PHP where the code is on the server).

Because you have not changed any of the views you don't need to follow this step but for a full deploy you would also copy any `.cshtml` or `.aspx` files and the usual suspects such as `.css` and `.js` etc to same folders on server as on the project.

I hope that is a good starter to get you going?

Comment: There are no .sln - would this be the case if the developer made the site, but did not need to supply them for the site to work? Therefore no changes could be made without the .sln?

Comment: That is unusual but you could just use the `.csproj` as that should work unless there are many projects but hopefully not.

Comment: Only that one project (as far as I can tell). I've downloaded VS2012 Web Express, and will try what's been suggested. Thanks everyone. (Though I may be back later when I discover compiling isn't as easy as you guys make it out to be :)

Comment: After getting VS2012 and loading in the project, when I try to compile it - it says xyz.EntityFramework.csproj does not exist. So I'm guessing I need another project that's being referenced in the one I want to recompile. As I don't see it, I'm guessing it wasn't needed for the compiled website, and the developer has it. Would this guess be accurate? As he wants about $1000 to make a minor change, it would appear that we are handcuffed without the other csproj, or is there a workaround to not having it? thx